# How does OpenSSH implement local port forward?

Tags: go, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I started a sshd(using [go-ssh](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)) to listen ssh-client,

and run `ssh  -L 2345:127.0.0.1:5244 127.0.0.1 -p 2022  -N`.

I didn't receive any message  from client (include "direct-tcpip" ), but I can access web through `127.0.0.1:2345`.

How does  OpenSSH implement local port forward?

I hope than I can receive "direct-tcpip" from client.

```
sshConn, ch, globalRequestCh, err := ssh.NewServerConn(conn, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Handshake  err", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("sshd serving", "ssh client", sshConn.RemoteAddr())

        
    go func() {
    // handle newChan
    for newChannel := range ch {
        log.Println("new channel", "type", newChannel.ChannelType())
        switch newChannel.ChannelType() {
        case "session":
                    
        case "direct-tcpip":
                    
        default:

            }
    }
    }()

    // handle globalRequest
    for globalRequest := range globalRequestCh {
    log.Println("global request", "type", globalRequest.Type)
    switch globalRequest.Type {
        case "tcpip-forward":

        case "cancel-tcpip-forward":

        default:
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found a sentence from this [article](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-June/079446.html) ,“I also can see no implementation of server-side handling of direct-tcpip“.

Comment: Sorry. I found that when I access the web, ssh client will send "direct-tcpip" to ssh server. I thought mistakenly  that it will send message before I access the web like "forward-tcpip" (remote port forward).